Selenium test fails on pipeline, but passes locally everytime I run it
I am developing a project, and started doing selenium tests to test the frontend.
The test I currently wrote works perfectly locally, but when push it to git, the pipeline fails everytime. Right now, I receive the following error:  org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException at LoginTest.java:42
EDIT: line 42 is driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:8080"), capabilities);
.gitlab-ci.yml
image: openjdk:19-slim

services:
  - name: selenium/standalone-chrome
    alias: chrome

stages:
  - build_annotation_tool
  - startSpringBoot
  - test

variables:
  #Java_Home: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
  GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"
  GRADLE_USER_HOME: ".gradle" # Change the gradle user home to cache the gradle dependencies
  SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED: "ALWAYS"
  PRING_JPA_SHOW_SQL: "true"
cache:
  key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
  paths: # Cache the gradle dependencies
    - .gradle/wrapper 
    - .gradle/caches
    - build/

before_script:
  - echo "Setting up the environment..."
  - export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH # Exporting Java path

build_annotation_tool:
  stage: build_annotation_tool
  script:
    - echo "Building the project..."
    - cd Annotation_Tool
    - chmod +x ./gradlew  # Change the gradlew file permission
    - ./gradlew clean assemble # Build the project
    - ./gradlew checkstyleMain checkstyleTest # Check the code style

startSpringBoot:
  stage: startSpringBoot
  dependencies:
        - build_annotation_tool
  script:
    - echo "Starting the Spring Boot application..."
    - cd Annotation_Tool
    - chmod +x ./gradlew  # Change the gradlew file permission
    - ./gradlew bootRun & # Start the Spring Boot application in the background
  timeout: 120s # Timeout for the Spring Boot application to start

test:
  stage: test
  dependencies:
    - startSpringBoot
  script:
    - echo "Running the tests..."
    - cd Annotation_Tool
    - chmod +x ./gradlew  # Change the gradlew file permission
    - ./gradlew test jacocoTestReport -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=drivers/Chrome/chromedriver.exe
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/reports/jacoco/test/html/index.html # Save the test reports
      - build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
  coverage: '/(\d+\.\d+|\d+)%/' # Regex to check the coverage

testFile ( the one that fails )
package frontend;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.Duration;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@SpringBootTest(classes = org.example.Main.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class LoginTest {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        // Set the path to the chromedriver executable
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers/Chrome/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        // Initialize the ChromeDriver
        if (System.getenv("CI") != null) {
            // We are in the CI environment, use remote WebDriver
            options.addArguments("--headless");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
            try {
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:8080"), capabilities);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        } else {
            // We are in the local environment, use local WebDriver
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoginInvalidAccount() {
        // Construct the file URL for the local HTML file
        String fileUrl = Paths.get("src/main/java/org/example/frontend/Login/Login.html").toUri().toString();
        // Open the local HTML file
        driver.get(fileUrl);

        // Find the username field and enter the username
        WebElement usernameField = driver.findElement(By.id("login-username"));
        usernameField.sendKeys("invalidUsername");

        // Find the password field and enter the password
        WebElement passwordField = driver.findElement(By.id("login-password"));
        passwordField.sendKeys("invalidPassword");

        // Find the login button and click it
        WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.id("subBtn"));
        loginButton.click();

        // Verify the login was successful by checking the URL or an element on the page
        //String expectedUrl = "src/main/java/org/example/frontend/Dashboard/Dashboard.html";
        //assertEquals(driver.getCurrentUrl(), expectedUrl);

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)); // 10 seconds timeout
        Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        // Verify the alert text
        String alertText = alert.getText();
        assertEquals(alertText, "Invalid login credentials. Please try again.");
        // Accept the alert to close it
        alert.accept();
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() {
        // Close the browser
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}

build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    id 'checkstyle'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

checkstyle {
    toolVersion "9.2.1"

    ignoreFailures = false
    maxErrors = 0
    maxWarnings = 0
    configFile = '../checkstyle.xml' as File
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.12"
}

test{
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
    jvmArgs '--add-opens', 'java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED'
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
    reports {
        xml.required = true
        html.required = true
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    implementation 'javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.7'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:3.0.0'
    implementation 'jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:3.0.0'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'

    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'

    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'

    implementation 'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:3.0.2'

    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'

    implementation 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8:19.6.0.0'
    implementation 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ucp:19.6.0.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi
    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.9'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.9'

    implementation 'com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.2'
    implementation 'javax.activation:activation:1.1.1'

    testImplementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.21.0'
}

The project contains chromedriver.exe file, that is the latest chrome driver I downloaded a few hours prior to this question ( version : 126.0.6478.55). The test always passes locally with no issues. We have been using java19 for the entire project, so any image that can allow me to use java19 and chrome driver would be ideal.
Above is the final configuration I tried.
I changed the dependencies, changed the pipeline multiple times, tried new images. So far the only image that worked is openjdk:19-slim, all the others I tried fail the entire project, not just this test, but maybe I did not find the right one. Also tried changing the configuration of the test file, changing the way I create the driver to use it in the pipeline.
